# Find out a row number for a specific row, after ordering by a sum

Tags: mysql

I have a table laid out like so:

```
wins(userid, wins, losses)
```

I am running a query like so to order the table:

```
SELECT winloss.userid AS userid, 
(winloss.wins*3) - winloss.losses AS winloss 
FROM site_win_loss AS winloss WHERE winloss.userid 
NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 32, 46, 90) ORDER BY winloss DESC
```

What this does is assigns each user their score, and orders them, in a leader board format. Now in my actual implementation I use a simple php count to place 1, 2, 3 ect beside there names, but I am aware that I can also do this:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
winloss.userid AS userid,
(winloss.wins*3) - winloss.losses AS winloss
FROM site_win_loss AS winloss, 
(select @rownum:=0) a
WHERE winloss.username NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 32, 46, 90)
ORDER BY winloss DESC
```

Now, lets say that the above returns me the following:

```
rank  | userid  | winloss
1     | 45      | 657
2     | 54      | 587
3     | 26      | 501
4     | 76      | 532
5     | 34      | 476
6     | 63      | 412
7     | 23      | 367
8     | 84      | 314
9     | 41      | 265
10    | 96      | 201
```

Is there anyway I could grab a specific row above? For example, if I wanted JUST user 41's details above, the SQL statement would return only this:

```
rank  | userid  | winloss
9     | 41      | 265
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be misunderstanding, but assuming you're generating a table from your above query, why couldn't you simply query that table using a simple select/where statement to get your specified record?  eg,

```
select *
from #ranktable
where userid = 41
```

Comment: how exactly would I execute that within the query I'm already running?

Comment: I was imagining you'd nest the above in order to create a temp/permanent table.

If that wasn't your plan, you could always put the above in its entirety in a subquery and use the query I included above to get the record you want:

select *
from ( [your query from above] ) a
where a.userid = 41

Comment: Yep, that was it. I think at the time I assumed (incorrectly it seems) that I could do it with some clever WHERE condition. I'll give you the tick as soon as I can click it. You got there first after all.

Comment: Well, you'd need to rank over the entire list before pulling the specific entry, so you'd need to do it as a subquery or stand-alone query.

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer query

```
Select *
FROM(
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
winloss.userid AS userid,
(winloss.wins*3) - winloss.losses AS winloss
FROM site_win_loss AS winloss, 
(select @rownum:=0) a
WHERE winloss.username NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 32, 46, 90)

)a
where a.userid = 41
```

Comment: That was exactly it. I'm actually a little upset that I spent so long writing out such a huge question, hahaha. One very small point. I had to add "AS temp" after the closing bracket, as it refused to run without an alias. I think at the time I assumed (incorrectly it seems) that I could do it with some clever WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that works without using a subquery (but may not really be any more efficient), is to use the HAVING clause.

Something like:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
    winloss.userid AS userid,
    (winloss.wins*3) - winloss.losses AS winloss
FROM site_win_loss AS winloss, 
    (select @rownum:=0) a
WHERE winloss.username NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 32, 46, 90)
HAVING rank = 9
ORDER BY winloss DESC
```

However, this has the undesired result of re-calculating rank in the new output, but it should give you the record you want.

EDIT: moved the position of HAVING.

Comment: Assuming a table with thousands upon thousands of users (although by then I'll just be calculating it once an hour in a cron and caching it), which would be more efficient? I like to delay caching for as long as possible as I think users tend to notice it.

Comment: In testing against a table I have with 270,000 records, I find the 'HAVING' statement above returns in 0.12 seconds, and the subquery approach returns in 0.26 seconds.

Comment: Here are my two queries: 

`SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
    u.uid AS userid,
    u.access AS winloss
FROM users AS u, 
    (select @rownum:=0) a
WHERE u.uid NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 32, 46, 90)
ORDER BY winloss DESC
HAVING rank = 9;

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
u.uid AS userid,
u.access AS winloss
FROM users AS u, 
    (select @rownum:=0) a
WHERE u.uid NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 32, 46, 90)
ORDER BY winloss DESC
) x
WHERE rank = 3;`

Comment: Hey Doug. Interesting problem. My server doesn't seem to want me to run HAVING after the ORDER BY in my existing query. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll edit that. HAVING is actually part of GROUP BY (it does work, though).

Comment: I may have discovered a problem Doug. You use HAVING rank, where as I need to pull the record based on userid. Is that possible?

Comment: If you need to preserve the rank and fitler by user_id, than the having clause won't work. I thought you wanted to grab the user with a specific rank within the list.

Comment: Pity. Thanks anyway Doug, very interesting idea either way :)